# Wireless Client missing from MAC table

Tags: switch, wifi, mac-address

I am currently having problems with Wireless Clients loosing network connectivity, though still displaying a connection to their Wireless Access Point.

I have 4 Wireless APs, each a Cisco WAP321 setup using Single Point Setup, hence they share a common SSID. These APs do not support transparent handover/roaming (as far as I can tell).

However, when a device loses connectivity it goes missing from the MAC address table on the switch, and re-appears once it regains connectivity (I guess this is the cause of my connectivity problems, rather than a symptom of).

What can I do to accurately diagnose and ultimately resolve this? Sure increasing the age time, may keep them in the MAC table, but this would surely affect there roaming capability, further adding to the problem.

Comment: Does your switch have any sort of mac security enabled?  Are you hitting the limit of the switch's mac table?

Comment: Nope, I haven't configured any port security on the switch. And from what I can tell online, my switches MAC table is big enough for 16k entrys, I shouldn't be anywhere near that with only about 200 devices on my LAN.